# Image size inside div in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How to make image inside div not to be bigger than the div? now I set width is set to 500px what is not a good solution.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">
   <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xm-12">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xm-12"">
    <img src="imagesource" class="img-responsive" width="500" height="auto">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the `width` and `height` attributes, just having the class `img-responsive` should make sure that the image width does not exceed the parent div width.

Comment: You have a typo in the 4th div, there is a `"` too much after `col-xm-12` and by the way it should be `col-xs-12`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting

```
img {
width:100%;
}
```

or

```
<img style="width:100%;"/>
```

will make sure that an `img` is never wider than its parent container.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove your inline styles (width and height) for `<img>`. Also remove double quotes here `col-xm-12"">`

Jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/oboshto/py2zs1vh/)